# fields overlapping in Responsive CSS

Tags: android, ios, css, responsive-design

I made a responsive form it looks nice in iPad but in iPhone and andriod phone (small s creen) it's Submit is overlapped by textfield. I tried to fix but but seems I need little help. Here is my code :

Demo : http://ithanku.t15.org/

```
* { 
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
 }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  form > div {
    margin: 0 0 15px 0; 
  }
  form > div > label,
  legend {
      width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  form > div > div,
  form > div > fieldset > div {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  input[type=text],
  input[type=email],
  input[type=url],
  input[type=password],
  textarea,
  select {
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  form > div > label,
    legend {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

FYI: I added above code in this stylesheet : http://ithanku.t15.org/index_files/style_002.css

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a negative margin being applied to the `div` wrapping the 'submit' button:

```
.gform_footer.top_label {
    float: right;
    margin: -58px 0 0 0;
}
```

If you change it to

```
.gform_footer.top_label {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}
```

the issue goes away.

You'd put that inside a media query to ensure it doesn't break your desktop layout:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:890px) {
    .gform_footer.top_label {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

I've left out the `float:right`, as you don't need to specify it twice.

Comment: Thank you, it works but button is still towards right so I made the change I added float:left; after margin: 0;